# Copying and pasting whole tabs from one workbook to another if their name contains certain word

Tags: vba, excel

Would someone be able to advise on below? I'm trying to write a code to copy sheets that in their name have *RTP* from a few workbooks to one. I got to below code but when I try to run it it basically crashes my Excel. I would be grateful for advice, if this is all completely wrong please let me know and I'll start again!

```
Sub RTP_reporting()
Dim WorkbookName As String
WorkbookName = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="New RTP report"

Workbooks.Open Filename:="https://addresshere"
ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="xxx"

Workbooks.Open Filename:="https://addresshere2"
ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="xxx"
```

And so on, for 9 files.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
 For Each ws In Sheets
  If LCase(ws.Name) Like "*RTP*" Then
        ws.Select
  End If
 Next

Windows("New RTP report.xlsx").Activate
Workbooks("New RTP report.xlsx").Paste
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="RTP_report_" & WorkbookName
```

And then I want to protect the previously opened workbooks and close them.

```
Windows("File1.xlsm").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password:="xxx"
ActiveWindow.Close

Windows("File2.xlsm").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password:="xxx"
ActiveWindow.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Your test here won't work `LCase(ws.Name) Like "*RTP*"` as you have one side in lower case and RTP in upper case ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this.

I added Workbook objects to make referencing easier (`Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("addresshere")`) and cleaned your code a bit, that should do the trick! ;)

```
Sub RTP_reporting()

Dim WorkbookName As String, _
    wbRep As Workbook, _
    wb1 As Workbook, _
    wb2 As Workbook, _
    ws As Worksheet

WorkbookName = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
Set wbRep = Workbooks.Add
wbRep.SaveAs Filename:="New RTP report"

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("https://addresshere")
wb1.Unprotect Password:="xxx"

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("https://addresshere2")
wb2.Unprotect Password:="xxx"

For Each ws In wb1.Sheets
    If InStr(1, LCase(ws.Name), "rtp") > 0 Then
        ws.Copy after:=wbRep.Sheets(wbRep.Sheets.Count)
    End If
Next
For Each ws In wb2.Sheets
    If InStr(1, LCase(ws.Name), "rtp") > 0 Then
        ws.Copy after:=wbRep.Sheets(wbRep.Sheets.Count)
    End If
Next ws

wbRep.SaveAs Filename:="RTP_report_" & WorkbookName

wb1.Protect Password:="xxx"
wb1.Close
wb2.Protect Password:="xxx"
wb2.Close

Set wbRep = Nothing
Set wb1 = Nothing
Set wb2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally do not like to use the `Active...` functions and `Activate` and `Select` methods in my VBA code because it can cause unexplained application errors and crashes. Instead I refer the objects I want to use with a variable

```
Dim Report as Workbook
set Report = Workbooks.Add ...
Report.SaveAs ...
```

Do the same for the source workbooks

```
dim Source as Workbook
set Source = Workbooks.Open ...
```

Now loop through the sheets and instead of select and copy, copy the sheet directly to the desired workbook

```
For Each ws in Source.sheets
    If ...
        ws.copy Before:= Report.Sheets(1)
    End If ..
Loop
```

Hope this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Barry - thank you for above tip, as a beginner I really appreciate all advice from practitioners!